# Google maps v3 - listen authentication successfully

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

According to Google Maps documentation, you can listen for authentication errors programatically by using window.gm_authFailure() function  (refer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors)

But are there anything to handle when authentication successfully?
Here is all I want: I hide the widget as default when loading, if the authentication successfully, then show that widget.

Comment: How about using the callback function when the Maps API loads?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API

Comment: That callback function is invoked after jscript file is loaded successfully, before the authentication progress.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could geocode something and if the response comes back OK (or ZERO_RESULTS), then you know you have authenticated successfully, and the success handler could be where you put your show widget code, if I understand your use case.